# Difference between " , " and " << " in cout in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

code :

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() 
{ 
    int i = 1;
    cout << "hello " << i  << " end" ;
    return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT : hello 1 end

this works fine but

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int main() 
{  
    int i = 1;
    cout << "hello " , i  , " end" ;
    return 0; 
}
```

OUTPUT: hello

why the above terminates with printing hello only?

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
std::cout << "hello " , i  , " end" ;
```

Because `,` has a lower operator precedence than `<<`, this will be evaluate to:

```cpp
(std::cout << "hello "), i  , " end" ;
```

First, `(std::cout << "hello ")` will be evaluate, printing `hello` .

Second, i would get evaluate. The value `i` will be return for the whole expression `(std::cout << "hello "), i`.

Third, `" end"` would get evaluate. The value `" end"`  will be return for the whole expression `((std::cout << "hello "), i ), " end" ;`